# Log levels in IoT Agent UL

Tags: fiware

I'm using IoTA-UL in Fiware.

I need to know what messages sent to IoTA-UL were well received and what don't (i.e. because of API KEY were invalid or ultralight message were malformed because the sender included some attribute that doesn't exist).

Right know I'm using `DEBUG` log level, but the log it's eating my disk. Is there any way to log what I want? `FATAL`, `ERROR`, `INFO` and `WARN` log levels don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

In the [IoT Agent UL documentation](https://github.com/Fiware/iot.IoTagent-UL/blob/master/docs/operations.md#logs), you can find a list with all log entries/messages that can appear in the IoTA logs.

I hope it can help you.